# Silent installation with autofill setup values

Tags: automation, autofill, silent-installer, gpo

I have a software that needs to be installed on a few machines on the network. However, it is not a simple installation like clicking I Agree > Next > Next. 
The users needs to enter some values in text fields, uncheck and check some checkboxes etc. Good things is that these values will be fixed for all users and
may not change.

Is there any way by which I can push (silently install) this package on all the computers and autoselect/autofill all the installation parameters??? I tried a tool SilentInstallBuilder but it is not able to autofill all the fields.

Comment: Can you provide more information on the software and the system? 
If the software uses install4j for the installation process than it is pretty easy.

Comment: Please post the installer otherwise nobody can help. Silent switches depends on the used software. See https://www.silent-install.net/installer/start